# Visual Basic . NET 8: How to add General Expressions?

Tags: vb.net

I wish to incorporate general expressions in my Visual Basic work.

Other than the basic inputting "Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions", I have no idea how to do put general expressions in my VB project.

However, I can create the expressions (so, all is not lost).

Any help, with examples, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and a more direct guide [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).